# Vue.js text input not to show the value of v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, textinput, v-model

Is there a way to make an input not to show the value of its pre-defined v-model in Vue.js?
For example, let's say I have an input that has `"value"` as its v-model and this v-model has been predefined somewhere else in the code. I don't want this input to show "value" inside it in the GUI without removing the v-model value. Something like hiding the v-model from GUI. Is it possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking and why you'd want to do it. Could you please clarify your question with a more concrete use-case?

Comment: I have a 4 step registration form. In the third page (step 3) there is a text input with v-model "promocode". But this promocde is defined on the first page. The user can enter a new promocode in the input in step 3 to over ride it if he wants to. That's why I don't want the user to see the value of promocode in the input. If he enters something new then the value of promocode would change, if not then we proceed with the initial value of promocode.

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer. I believe you'll find the answer below 

Answer (score 1):

You can *not* bind the value and set the value in the `@input` event.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   foo: 'some default value',
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @input="foo = $event.target.value">
  <p>{{foo}}</p>
</div>
```